# Stokes relations for a glass slab

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, glass

[Stokes relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_relations) describes the transmission and reflection coefficients at a boundary between materials of different refractive indices, derived using a time-reversal argument. As far as I understand, this time-reversal argument should also applies to reflection and transmission of light incident on a glass slab (with two boundaries). Let the transmission and reflection coefficients of light incident from the top and bottom surface be $r$, $t$ and $r'$, $t'$ respectively, then we should have the following:

[image]

so the reflection coefficients of light incident from top and bottom have opposite sign.

But from a most basic symmetry argument, shouldn't they be the same regardless of incident direction? They both go from air to glass, and the slab is symmetric.

Why is either of these arguments wrong?

A related question about the front mirror of an optical cavity is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/463862/), the answer being that for a mirror the reflected light has $\pi$ shift on the side with coating and no shift on the side without. I know this is the case in reality, but this doesn't answer the question about Stokes relations, because in deriving it no such asymmetry is assumed. So to make the question clearer here I consider just a simple slab with no difference on the two sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you neglected is the **multiple** interactions at the **two** air-glass interfaces as described in one of the answers in [the link that you have provide about the Fabry-Perot cavity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463862/reflection-transfer-function-of-a-fabry-perot-cavity).

[image]

Thus the  equations $Ett'+Er^2 = E$ and $Etr'+Ert = 0$ are only valid when considering **one** air-glass interface, otherwise you have many more rays to consider.

Comment: I also thought about the multiple interactions, but what I still don't understand is the following: (assuming the glass is lossless) in the end the light is either reflected back or transmitted through. If one considers all the reflected and transmitted rays combined as R and T, why are Stokes relations not directly applicable to the combined rays, just like for the one interface case? Does the process not have time-reversal symmetry?

Comment: Time reversal will work but you will need to be adding infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks are to [Farcher](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/104696/farcher) for answering the question. I elaborate here in case it's unclear to others.

The symmetry argument is correct; $r$ and $r'$ should be equal in this case. [Therefore I believe the statement in many texts about optical cavities (Chapter 3 of Warren Nagourney's Quantum Electronics for Atomic Physics, for example) is wrong; the minus sign of the direct reflection from the input mirror does not come from Stokes relations, but from the phase shift attributed to the coating of the mirror.]

The reason why one cannot directly apply Stokes relations on the total reflected and transmitted light is as follows. As the glass slab has two interfaces, there will be infinite series of reflected and transmitted rays, and because the slab has a finite thickness, there is a finite difference between the time each ray leaves the slab surface (the buildup of the total reflected and transmitted field will, in fact, take infinite time, though this is not of any practical significance because later terms in the geometrical series are negligible). The time difference matters because it leads to phase difference, which in turn leads to different results when you add up complex amplitudes. In the time-reversal case, if one considers the combined reflected and transmitted rays as shown in the question, it is assumed that all rays impinge on the slab at the same time, leading to the wrong result of $r+r'=0$. Instead, as one goes from right to left (in the direction of time in the reversal case), time-reversal symmetry is automatically guaranteed by Stokes relations at each point a ray contacts a *single* surface (red circles), and Stokes relations don't provide any additional information about the total reflection and transmission coefficients of the whole slab.
[image]